# Mosaico Install Fail -- DB Error

Tags: wordpress, extension, error, mosaico

So this weekend I purchased hosting via CiviHosting for a WP/CiviCRM setup.  Most things have been setup without much issue, however, Mosaico will not install.  It fails with a rather generic, 'DB Error: Syntax error'.

Mosaico Install version is 3.5.1709296836
Civi is version 5.67.0
WP is version 6.4.3
PHP is 8.3.2
MySQL is v8.0.35

Its not likely related, but I was also unable to install CiviVolunteer, though in troubleshooting that it appears to be on borrowed time.

Here is  error log:

```
    2024-03-04 04:05:01+0000  [error] 
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "DB Error: syntax error"
  "code" => null
  "exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#3165
    #message: "DB Error: syntax error"
    #code: -2
    #file: "/home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php"
    #line: 138
    #cause: null
    -_trace: null
    -errorData: array:8 [
      "error_code" => -2
      "sql" => ":  Undefine_e112a5f4_after_insert"
      "debug_info" => """
        DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS civicrm_value_civivolunteer_\n
        :  Undefine_e112a5f4_after_insert [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':  Undefine_e112a5f4_after_insert' at line 2]
        """
      "entity" => "Extension"
      "action" => "install"
      "is_error" => 1
      "error_message" => "DB Error: syntax error"
      "debug_information" => ":  Undefine_e112a5f4_after_insert"
    ]
    trace: {
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php:138 {
        civicrm_api3(string $entity, string $action, array $params = [])
        › if (is_array($result) && !empty($result['is_error'])) {
        ›   throw new CRM_Core_Exception($result['error_message'], CRM_Utils_Array::value('error_code', $result, 'undefined'), $result);
        › }
      }
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php:187 { …}
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:614 { …}
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php:144 { …}
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php:43 { …}
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203 { …}
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103 { …}
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:355 { …}
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php:364 { …}
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php:170 { …}
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php:110 { …}
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:322 { …}
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1199 { …}
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:324 { …}
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:348 { …}
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-includes/plugin.php:517 { …}
      /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-admin/admin.php:259 { …}
    }
  }
]


2024-03-04 04:05:01+0000  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(443): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Core_Exception))
#2 /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1199): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#3 /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#4 /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#5 /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#6 /home/friendsofthe/www/www/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#7 {main}
```

Comment: Have you raised a ticket with CiviHosting?  They are very helpful.

Comment: Ticket raised — first response was that it looked like a CiviVolunteer bug. 

CiviVolunteer never installed fully as  it had a DB error too. I cannot remove nor install it either —  it seems I’ve not been able to install anything since then.

Comment: CiviHosting removed CiviVolunteer and suggested a remove/reinstall of CiviCRM entirely as it's brand new.

Deleted the Plugin and database, reuploaded Civi via wordpress plugin gui without issue.  However, a fatal error was thrown when installing...  Waiting on suggestion from CiviHosting on next steps...

Comment: Do you get the same problems if you use php 8.1 or 8.2?

Comment: I don’t believe I have the option to change this, however CiviHosting reinstalled for me and I’ll try again. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No solution found — As this was an a new install and not yet populated, CiviHosting  deleted CiviCRM and reinstalled for me.